# Unable to upload xsl file with multiple sheets..[FileUploadException: Stream closed]

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I tried various permutation an combination and [googled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160545/could-not-parse-multipart-servlet-request-nested-exception-is-org-apache-common) as well,when  I am uploading xsl file with multiplesheet i am getting following Exception-

> org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not
>   parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream closed] with
>   root cause java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Below is my code-

```
    <form name="upload" th:action="@{/util/uploadExcel}" action="/util/uploadExcel" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
     <input type="file" name="fileData"  path="fileData"  />
     <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/util")
    public class UtilController {

    @RequestMapping(value=("/uploadExcel"),headers=("content-type=multipart/*"),method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView uploadExcel(@RequestParam("fileData") CommonsMultipartFile file,BindingResult result) {
        utilService.uploadData(file);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("paidAnalysis/index");
        return modelAndView;
    }


    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }

}
```

MoreOver I have added dependency for 'commons-fileupload' in my project.

When I upload any csv file other than xsl I am getting-

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
>   Required CommonsMultipartFile parameter 'fileData' is not present

Comment: @BalusC my pleasure you seen this,I am struck with this last couple of hours,please show me path to move forward

Comment: Accept RequestParam as MultipartFile instead of CommonsMultipartFile. It will work.

Comment: I have tried with both :(